# WCF UriTemplate won't match a single string parameter with slashes (/'s)

Tags: .net, wcf, uritemplate

Here is the scenario, I have a WCF service call that takes one string parameter and that string has slashes in it (e.g. "123/456.xml").  I want to setup a UriTemplate like this "/{file}" so that I can access the method at http://www.example.com/File.svc/123/456.xml rather than http://www.example.com/File.svc/GetFile?file=123/456.xml.

Is this possible with UriTemplate?

- I realize that I could setup a UriTemplate like "/{directory}/{file}" but that is not an option because there is a variable number of directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I found a solution on MSDN.  UriTemplates support wildcard segments which basically mean the rest of the path.  So I can specify a UriTemplate like "/{*file}" and it will work as expected.

- MSDN docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675245.aspx
- Better explanation: http://hyperthink.net/blog/uritemplate-match/